# Find $y'$ for the equation: $xe^{-y/2} + ye^{-x/2} = \sin(x^2+y^2)$

Tags: derivatives

Find $y'$ for the equation:
$$
xe^{-y/2} + ye^{-x/2} = \sin(x^2+y^2)
$$

I have tried all ways I know, but I always have the problem of not noticing the important point. And end up going beyond in trying different methods.

We took and I tried the Implicit differentiation and the derivative of the logarithmic functions and I have been trying using those.
**(Note after answer. Apparently, all implicit functions we tried before, you would be able to replace the y's. Not this one though)**

I have tried taking the derivative in multiple points of using these ways to get some numbers that I can work out but I didn’t get any thing useful.

I tried using the inverse of sin or expanding it.

I have reached equations like:
$$
\frac{y+x}{2} + \ln\left(\frac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{x\sqrt{e^x}+y\sqrt{e^y}}\right) = 0
$$
or
$$
\frac{1-xy’}{\sqrt{e^x}} + \frac{y’-y/2}{\sqrt{e^y}} = \cos(x^2+y^2) (2x+2yy’)
$$
and couple other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your knowledge of the chain rule and the product rule, break the implicit function into parts. Thus:

$${d\over dx}xe^{-y/2}=x\cdot -{1\over 2}y'e^{-y/2} + e^{-y/2}$$

Then:

$${d\over dx}ye^{-x/2}=y\cdot -{1\over 2}e^{-x/2} + y'\cdot e^{-x/2}$$

Finally, the other side:

$${d\over dx}\sin(x^2+y^2)=(2x+2yy')\cos(x^2+y^2)$$

Combining everything together:

$$-{1\over 2}xy'e^{-y/2} + e^{-y/2} -{1\over 2}ye^{-x/2} + y'e^{-x/2} = (2x+2yy')\cos(x^2+y^2)$$

Then solve for $y'$.

Comment: my problem with this is, we always replace y in the end with it's equation so the equation ends up with only x's and It looks rather difficult with all this y's in the exponents to get to now whats y in the 1st place. I should ask the prof if we don't need to get rid of the y's here.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAlattas Why are you replacing $y$ with $x$s? You have an *implicit function*, that *relates $x$ and $y$* through an equation, not an input $x$ and an output $y$. The derivative, when applied to implicit curves gives you the derivative *at a point*, not an $x$-value.

Comment: true, this is the first implicit function that we try to get their derivative (it looks nice graphically) and we won't be able to get it with only x's. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really have much idea how you got *either* of your equations, and they both appear to be rather wrong. The point of the exercise is to use the chain rule and implicitly differentiate. For example, the derivative of the first term on the left is

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} x e^{-y/2} &= e^{-y/2} \frac d {dx} x + x \frac{d}{dx} e^{-y/2} \\
&= e^{-y/2} + x e^{-y/2} \frac d {dx} \left(-\frac y2\right) \\
&= e^{-y/2} - \frac 1 2 xe^{-y/2} y'.
\end{align}

Treat the other two parts similarly, and you'll be left with a linear equation to solve for $y'$.

Comment: But is there a way to end up with finding what y equal to replace them and get an equation with only x's, that's my problem with this.

Comment: It is extremely doubtful that you can solve for $y$ as a function of $x$ here.